# How can I concatenate dynamically tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have to generate dynamically report tables year by year in MySQL with a stored procedure. Example

```
Table year1
Year1 col1 col2 col3 

Table year2
Year2 col1 col2 col3
```

In

```
Table3
Year1 col1 col2 col3 Year2 col1 col2 col3
```

It's like a join but dynamic. If the user want 3 consecutive years, result should be a single table in output with all the columns inside

My situation with 1 table/year. I would like to extend this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Sp_DettaglioCapitolo`(in varAnno smallint,in varCategoria int,in varCapitolo int)
BEGIN

declare cur_idProcedura int;
declare cur_descrizioneEstesa char(200);
declare finished integer default 0;

declare varCapitoloIntestazione varchar(10) default 'Tutti';


declare varCategoriaString varchar(100) default '';

declare nrProcedure int;
declare descrizioneEstesa char(200);
declare nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato int;
declare impegniCompetenza decimal(20,2);
declare impegniLetteraF decimal(20,2);
declare pagamentiCompetenza decimal(20,2);
declare pagamenti decimal(20,2);


declare tot_nrProcedure int default 0;
declare tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato int default 0;
declare tot_impegniCompetenza decimal(20,2) default 0;
declare tot_impegniLetteraF decimal(20,2) default 0;
declare tot_pagamentiCompetenza decimal(20,2) default 0;
declare tot_pagamenti decimal(20,2) default 0;



declare cursoreTabella cursor for
    select idtipoprocedura, descrizionebreve from tipoprocedura
    where idtipoprocedura in (1,2,3,7,8,9)
    order by idtipoprocedura; 


declare cursoreTabella2 cursor for
    select idtipoprocedura, descrizionebreve from tipoprocedura
    where idtipoprocedura >=10
    order by idtipoprocedura; 


declare cursoreTabella1 cursor for
    select idtipoprocedura, descrizionebreve from tipoprocedura
    where idtipoprocedura in (4,5,6)
    order by idtipoprocedura; 




declare continue handler for not found set finished = 1;



drop table if exists tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno;
create temporary table tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa char(200),
                                                        nrProcedure int,
                                                        nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato int,
                                                        impegniCompetenza decimal(20,2),
                                                        impegniLetteraF decimal(20,2),
                                                        pagamentiCompetenza decimal(20,2),
                                                        pagamenti decimal(20,2));

case when varCapitolo <> 0 then                                                        
set varCategoriaString = concat('Categoria: ', varCategoria, ' - ', 'Capitolo: ',varCapitolo);
when varCapitolo = 0 then
set varCategoriaString = concat('Categoria: ', varCategoria, ' - ', 'Capitolo: ',varCapitoloIntestazione);
end case;


                                                                        insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values (varCategoriaString,null,null,null,null,null,null);




                                                        insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('ACQUISTI EXTRA CONSIP',null,null,null,null,null,null);

open cursoreTabella;
loopTabella: loop
    fetch cursoreTabella into
        cur_idProcedura,cur_descrizioneEstesa;

if finished = 1 then
    leave loopTabella;
end if;

    set descrizioneEstesa = cur_descrizioneEstesa;
    set nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = fn_DettaglioCapitoloNrProcedureAnnoSelezionato(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoImpegniCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set nrProcedure = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoNrProcedure(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniLetteraF = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoLetteraF(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamentiCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoPagamentiCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamenti = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPagamenti(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);


    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti);


    set tot_nrProcedure = tot_nrProcedure + nrProcedure;
    set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato + nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato;
    set tot_impegniCompetenza = tot_impegniCompetenza + impegniCompetenza;
    set tot_impegniLetteraF = tot_impegniLetteraF + impegniLetteraF;
    set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = tot_pagamentiCompetenza + pagamentiCompetenza;
    set tot_pagamenti = tot_pagamenti + pagamenti;

end loop;

    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('TOTALE ACQUISTI EXTRA CONSIP',tot_nrProcedure,tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,tot_impegniCompetenza,tot_impegniLetteraF,tot_pagamentiCompetenza,tot_pagamenti);

set tot_nrProcedure = 0;
set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = 0;
set tot_impegniCompetenza = 0;
set tot_impegniLetteraF = 0;
set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = 0;
set tot_pagamenti = 0;


set finished = 0;








                                                        insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('ACQUISTI TRAMITE CONSIP',null,null,null,null,null,null);

open cursoreTabella1;
loopTabella1: loop
    fetch cursoreTabella1 into
        cur_idProcedura,cur_descrizioneEstesa;

if finished = 1 then
    leave loopTabella1;
end if;

    set descrizioneEstesa = cur_descrizioneEstesa;
    set nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = fn_DettaglioCapitoloNrProcedureAnnoSelezionato(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoImpegniCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set nrProcedure = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoNrProcedure(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniLetteraF = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoLetteraF(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamentiCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoPagamentiCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamenti = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPagamenti(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);


    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti);


    set tot_nrProcedure = tot_nrProcedure + nrProcedure;
    set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato + nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato;
    set tot_impegniCompetenza = tot_impegniCompetenza + impegniCompetenza;
    set tot_impegniLetteraF = tot_impegniLetteraF + impegniLetteraF;
    set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = tot_pagamentiCompetenza + pagamentiCompetenza;
    set tot_pagamenti = tot_pagamenti + pagamenti;

end loop;

    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('TOTALE ACQUISTI TRAMITE CONSIP',tot_nrProcedure,tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,tot_impegniCompetenza,tot_impegniLetteraF,tot_pagamentiCompetenza,tot_pagamenti);

set tot_nrProcedure = 0;
set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = 0;
set tot_impegniCompetenza = 0;
set tot_impegniLetteraF = 0;
set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = 0;
set tot_pagamenti = 0;

set finished = 0;






                                                        insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('VARIE',null,null,null,null,null,null);

open cursoreTabella2;
loopTabella2: loop
    fetch cursoreTabella2 into
        cur_idProcedura,cur_descrizioneEstesa;

if finished = 1 then
    leave loopTabella2;
end if;

    set descrizioneEstesa = cur_descrizioneEstesa;
    set nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = fn_DettaglioCapitoloNrProcedureAnnoSelezionato(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoImpegniCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set nrProcedure = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoNrProcedure(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set impegniLetteraF = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoLetteraF(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamentiCompetenza = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPerAnnoPagamentiCompetenza(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);
    set pagamenti = fn_DettaglioCapitoloPagamenti(varAnno, varCategoria, varCapitolo, cur_idProcedura);


    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti);


    set tot_nrProcedure = tot_nrProcedure + nrProcedure;
    set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato + nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato;
    set tot_impegniCompetenza = tot_impegniCompetenza + impegniCompetenza;
    set tot_impegniLetteraF = tot_impegniLetteraF + impegniLetteraF;
    set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = tot_pagamentiCompetenza + pagamentiCompetenza;
    set tot_pagamenti = tot_pagamenti + pagamenti;

end loop;

    insert into tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno (descrizioneEstesa,nrProcedure,nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,impegniCompetenza,impegniLetteraF,pagamentiCompetenza,pagamenti)
                                        values ('TOTALE VARIE',tot_nrProcedure,tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato,tot_impegniCompetenza,tot_impegniLetteraF,tot_pagamentiCompetenza,tot_pagamenti);

set tot_nrProcedure = 0;
set tot_nrProcedureAnnoSelezionato = 0;
set tot_impegniCompetenza = 0;
set tot_impegniLetteraF = 0;
set tot_pagamentiCompetenza = 0;
set tot_pagamenti = 0;

set finished = 0;






select * from tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno;
drop temporary table tabellaDettaglioCapitoloPerAnno;

END
```

result

```
'Categoria: 27 - Capitolo: 2270', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'ACQUISTI EXTRA CONSIP', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'procedura aperta', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'
'procedura ristretta', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'
'procedura negoziata', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'
...
'TOTALE VARIE', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'
```

should be something like this at the end

[image]

How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Please add some example with data and table structure and expected output.

Comment: just added, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a JOIN, but be carefully, because both tables have to be well joined or it will lead in much more records than you expect.
You'll have to create some metadata as I explain you in next example. I face a situation similar to yours som years ago.

```sql
SELECT
Year1, col1, col2, col3, Year2, col1, col2, col3
FROM 
year1 INNER JOIN year2
ON (___Here you have to Join Data with "according columns"___)
```

In your case, "according columns" surely will not be the listed columns in your example (Year1, col1, col2, etc).
These columns will have to containt some data which contents will only be to fit in your SQL to create the report in that way.
Call it "your own metadata".

Hope this guidelines help.

PS: If you already have a function per year in VBA, Why dont you format a worksheet?
You can pass the year and a starting cell where to begin formatting. So you can format the report how you need just adding a cells gap for every year you have.
For example, for first year you can start at column 1, for secon year at column 5 and so on: ((Iteration*4)+1)  <---Iteration starting with zero.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but the main problem is that i don't know how many years i have to compute in my procedure, so i have to do something like a prepared statement that compose my final query i think

Comment: Ok, you could expand my example with multiple JOINS. The metadata columns are only to fit and create linear.horizontal resultset avoiding cartesian calculation.